# What does "register" mean in "babel/register"

Tags: babeljs, definition

In order to do runtime transformations in Babel you need to require and use `babel-core/register`. I have no idea what `register` means in this sense, i.e. the actual definition.

[The page isn't very helpful.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-register)

What does this actually mean?

Comment: Babel's non-documentaion is getting tiresome. They need to start including some motivation about packages rather than simply documenting the options.

Answer (score 29):

The purpose of babel is to transpile your js current code to an understandable version of js for the given environment, tool, framework you're using. Those vary as listed here, *[How to use Babel with your tool of choice.](https://babeljs.io/setup/)*
In the node environment, babel does not exist as part of its core APIs, so it needs to be added as an npm package first, (my example is for @babel 7.x ). And because babel is separated to accommodate different tools, we need to add @babel/core for the core functionality along with @babel/preset-env which enables transforms for ES2015+.

```
npm install @babel/core @babel/preset-env --save-dev
```

or

```
npm i -D @babel/core @babel-preset
```

now as we use babel we want the tell node about the available preset by setting up a .babelrc file in the root directory, [more on that found here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files)

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

now to get to the register aspect. Because of the nature of ES6 modules as [explained here](https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/74efi7/do_i_need_babel/), if we want to run babel without a build step like webpack or rollup, and run files using babel 'on the fly' we need to register babel into node's runtime *The require hook will bind itself to node’s require and automatically compile files on at runtime. This is equivalent to CoffeeScript’s coffee-script/register.* [reference from babel usage docs for babel-register found here](https://old.babeljs.io/docs/usage/babel-register/). Therefore, along with the previous npm install, we'll also need to add `@babel/register`:

```
npm install @babel/register --save-dev
```

or

```
npm i -D @babel/register
```

Now we can use it, either require "@babel/register" in the application files by one of two means, either in a file (generally, in the `index.js` file that is the entry point in your app and contains requires to other files) or add it in when using the cli.

```
// in .js file
require("@babel/register");
```

or

```
// in command line, don't add it to the .js file but instead use the -r flag for require
npx -r @babel/register index.js
```

(*more on npx can be [found here](https://medium.com/@maybekatz/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner-55f7d4bd282b)*)

As an option to adding the .babelrc, it can be skipped by instead adding a "babel" property within the package.json file as an option, ex.

```
//package.json in root
...,
"babel": {
  "presets":[
    "@babel/preset-env"
   ]
},
...
```

While the above was for babel 7, an example in babel 6 can be found from a great teacher's github, [Josh Miller, here](https://github.com/joshdmiller/js-test-boilerplate) (view his package.json file)
Hope this helps for an understanding of 'register' needs.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer** => Babel can help us in 2 situations:

### 1. Run code without build code (transform code on the fly - runtime compiling):

- The babel-register method:

```
require("@babel/register")();
```

- The babel-node method:

```
babel-node index.js
```

Read more: [babel-node vs babel-register](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42370331/5062890)

### 2. Build code

```
babel src --out-dir lib
```