# babel-node vs babel-register in development

Tags: babeljs, babel-node, babel-register

Is there any difference between using babel-register or babel-node **when running my code in development**? The two options are:

1. `require('babel-register')({
   "presets": ["es2015"]
   });` at entry-point.js and npm start script `node entry-point.js`
2. simply have npm start script `babel-node entry-point.js --preset=es2015`

Do they do the exact same thing? And is one way recommended over the other?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I asked around at work and got an answer. I'm going to post it here in case anyone else is interested.

`babel-node` basically calls `babel-register` internally. see [source](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-cli/src/_babel-node.js#L30-L36). The differences are

1. when using `babel-node` the entry-point itself will also run through babel vs. `babel-register` only files required after `babel-register` is required will be run through babel.
2. if you need `babel-polyfill` (for eg. generators) `babel-node` will pull it in automatically, vs. `babel-register` you'd need to do that yourself. This is something to keep in mind when building for production. If you need `babel-polyfill` and you are using `babel-node` in development, you'd need to make sure you are building w/ `babel-polyfill` when building for production.

One way doesn't seem to be recommended over the other. However, `babel-node` is a little cleaner b/c it'll keep the `require ('babel-register')` out of the codebase. It also seems to be a bit more intuitive to someone new to all this stuff.