# Spread Operator throws SyntaxError even after Babel Configuration in Webstorm 2018.3

Tags: node.js, webstorm, babeljs

### Webstorm / OS

`Webstorm 2018.3/Windows 10`

### Node/NPM

`v8.0.0/6.4.1`

#### Steps followed

1. [JetBrains ECMAScript6 in Webstorm Babel FileWatcher](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/05/ecmascript-6-in-webstorm-transpiling/#babelfilewatcher)

   I added `Babel` through the steps
2. For a local repository I installed `npm i --save-dev @babel/cli @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/plugin-object-proposed-rest-spread`
3. added `.babelrc` in the root folder with following:

   ```
    {
      "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
      "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"]
    }
   ```
4. Configured my Run Configuration for `npm start` since my `package.json` has `"start": nodemon app.js` in it.

### Application

I am using `mongoose` to store and obtain information from MongoDB and using GraphQL to provide an endpoint for queries/mutation

here is one of my `mutation` (function) within my code:

```
 createEvent: (args) => {
            const event = new Event({
               title: args.eventInput.title,
               description: args.eventInput.description,
               price: +args.eventInput.price,
               date: new Date(args.eventInput.date)
            });
            return event
                .save()
                .then(result => {
                    console.log(result);
                    return { ...result._doc };
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    throw err;
                });
        }
```

**Error**:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
```

#### Steps Followed Again

According to [SE Query to Configure Babel with Webstorm for node.js project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44213145/configure-babel-with-webstorm-to-use-es6-with-webstorm-node-js-project) I tried creating a `node.js app` but I now get an Error:

```
 Error: querySrv ENOTFOUND _mongodb._tcp.undefined-p8e7q.mongodb.net
  at errnoException (dns.js:50:10)
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:244:19)
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'querySrv',
  hostname: '_mongodb._tcp.undefined-p8e7q.mongodb.net'
```

I now instead replace `{ ...result._doc }` with `return result._doc` and the code works fine but I wish to use the spread operator within other blocks of code.

I understand that the error has nothing to do with `Webstorm` but I do not see any other alternative to this problem

### Edit

**File Watcher Babel**
[image: File Watcher for WebStorm]

**NPM Configuration**
[image: NPM Configuration]

**Node.js Configuration**
created by right-click on `app.js` file and `Create 'app.js'` from menu. I installed `npm i --save-dev @babel/register` and changed it to `-r @babel/register` as mentioned in the blog
[image: Node JS configuration]

#### `app.js`

```
const express = require('express'); // Add Express Module
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // Add Body-Parser Middleware for JSON handling in Requests
const graphqlHttp = require('express-graphql'); // Add Middleware for GraphQL Resolvers over Express HTTP
const { buildSchema } = require('graphql'); // Javascript Object-Destructuring (pull objects from packages)
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); // MongoDB Third-Party package


const Event = require('./models/event'); // MongoDB Event Model

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // JSON parsing Middleware added

app.use('/graphql', graphqlHttp({
    schema: buildSchema(`
        type Event {
            _id: ID!
            title: String!
            description: String!
            price: Float!
            date: String!
        }

        input EventInput {
            title: String!
            description: String!
            price: Float!
            date: String!
        }

        type RootQuery {
            events: [Event!]!
        }

        type RootMutation {
            createEvent(eventInput: EventInput): Event
        }

        schema {
            query: RootQuery
            mutation: RootMutation
        }
    `),
    rootValue: {
        events: () => {
            return Event.find()
                .then(events => {
                    return events.map( event => {
                        event._doc._id = event.id;
                        return event._doc;
                    });
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    throw err;
                })
        },
        createEvent: (args) => {
            const event = new Event({
               title: args.eventInput.title,
               description: args.eventInput.description,
               price: +args.eventInput.price,
               date: new Date(args.eventInput.date)
            });
            return event
                .save()
                .then(result => {
                    console.log(result);
                    return { ...result._doc };
                    // return result._doc
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    throw err;
                });

        }
    },
    graphiql: true
}));

mongoose.connect(
    `mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGO_USER}:${process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD}@${process.env.MONGO_CLUSTER_NAME}-p8e7q.mongodb.net/${process.env.MONGO_DB_NAME}?retryWrites=true`)
    .then( () => {
        app.listen(3000);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

**`package.json`**

I added some weird babel packages as some desperate attempt to get it up and running which is in `dev-dependencies`

```
{
  "name": "graphql-express-app",
  "version": "0.0.4",
  "description": "Academind's YouTube Series on GraphQL-Express-React",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "graphql",
    "express",
    "node.js"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-stage-2": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-graphql": "^0.7.1",
    "graphql": "^14.0.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you compile your code with babel (using file watcher) prior to passing it to node.js? if yes, what does your file watcher look like? what is `app.js` - your original source file, or a file generated by Babel (via file watcher)?

Comment: I will update the question with more details via snapshots.

Comment: @lena already updated the query with more information from the IDE and related files.

Comment: I actually started with simple `npm start` configuration and once I wrote the `...` operator in the code I got some problem and then I went ahead and did all the configuration mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stripped down your example and added a minimal version of what you need to get it up and running.

Basically what you're missing is the part where babel actually goes and transpiles your code. I don't know if webstorm does that for you, I'm using VS code.

**.babelrc**:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

**package.json** (deps and scripts only, rest ommited):

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node app.js"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
  "@babel/node": "^7.2.2",
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.2.0",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
  "nodemon": "^1.18.9"
}
```

Minimal **app.js**:

```
const o = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
};
const o2 = { ...o };
console.log(o2);
// Outputs: { a: 'a', b: 'b' }
```

You can save yourself from having to transpile nodejs code by using a recent version. The spread operator is supported in node from version 8.6.0 up: https://node.green/#ES2018-features-object-rest-spread-properties

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a ton! I managed to take into consideration both your suggestions. Updated `node v8.0.0 -> 10.5.0` and your setting for babel.